# Hi i have a 'str' object has no attribute 'get' problem in python-tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, get, tkinter-entry

it doesn't work
i want it to get a number then click those button bellow and then get the result in the message box what should i do?!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
from tkinter import ttk

win=Tk()
#here is my problem 
def household():
    global s
    global math
    math="multiply"
    x=int(E.get())
    s=(x/100)*500
    b="your bill is:"+str(s)
    messagebox.showinfo("result",b)
def commercial():
    global s
    x=int(E.get())
    if x<=4000000:
        s=(x/100)*750
household()            
commercial()
E=Entry(win,bg="#87CEFA")
b1=Button(win,text="Household",bg="#4169E1",command=household) 
b3=Button(win,text="commercial",bg="#4169E1",command=commercial)
E.place(x=100,y=85,width=100,height=20)
b1.place(x=100,y=165,width=100,height=30)
b3.place(x=150,y=165,width=100,height=30)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "what should i do?!" You should start by reading [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and trying to find the problem yourself, which starts with trying to *read* and *understand* the error message. Where does it occur? What do you think the error means? What do you suppose is the cause of that problem? Error messages [contain valuable information besides the actual error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `household()` and `commercial()` before you define E. Because you are doing a wildcard import (`from tkinter import *`) you're importing the constant `E` from tkinter, which is defined as the string "e".

The solution is:

- don't do wildcard imports import tkinter with `import tkinter as tk` and then use `tk.` as a prefix for all tkinter objects (`tk.Entry(...)`, `tk.Button(...)`, etc)
- Make sure your code runs in the correct order. If you have functions that depend on a variable, make sure those functions aren't called before the variable is defined.